# Identify phone number, then match country code and then assign correct name in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science, data-cleaning

I have a data frame of "CDR" (Call Detail Records) with the first 5 digits of phone numbers and another data frame called "CC" with country codes and country names.

```
PhoneNumber <- c("52431", "44781", "N/A") #18 million rows of data
CDR <- data.frame(PhoneNumber)               
CDR

CountryCode <- c("52", "44")
CountryName <- c("Mexico", "UK")
cc <- data.frame(CountryName, CountryCode)
cc

#The output I desire
C_CountryName <- c("Mexico", "UK", "N/A")
CDR <- data.frame(PhoneNumber, C_CountryName)
CDR
```

I have thought of it this way:

```
x <- 1
for(x == 2)
{index of y <- cc$CountryCode where (cc$CountryCode == x) (assigns country 
code to y)
y is then matched in all rows of CDR$PhoneNumber and returns index of 
CDR$PhoneNumbers where y is a partial match of CDR$PhoneNumber.
y <- cc$CountryName where (cc$CountryName == x)
x++
}
```

So, at the end of the loop x is incremented, until all countries are matched, then I can mutate y to df1.

I have tried, replace, match, grepl, str_detect in few combinations but I am unable to get the desired output.

I hope you can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example of dataset with `dput`

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`, substituting `df1` and `df2` for `df`.

Comment: We do really need representative samples of all three data structures in code blocks.

Comment: Updated the code to something easily reproducible. Apologies, I thought giving a reference would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a set of regex patterns on 18 million rows of data will be extremely inefficient, and as other commenters have already pointed out, country calling codes can be more or less than 2 digits, so you're likely to run into significant other problems. That being said, you could use one of the `apply` family of functions to run each row of data through one of the `grep` family of functions to match arbitrarily long beginning digits like this...

```
PhoneNumber <- c("52431", "44781", "1512234", "21234567", "N/A")
CountryCode <- c("52", "44", "1", "212")
CountryName <- c("Mexico", "UK", "USA", "Morocco")

regex <- paste0("^", CountryCode)

matchname <- 
  sapply(PhoneNumber, USE.NAMES = FALSE, function(x) {
    matches <- sapply(regex, function(y) grepl(y, x))
    if (any(matches)) {
      CountryName[matches]
    } else {
      NA_character_
    }
  })

data.frame(PhoneNumber, matchname)
#   PhoneNumber matchname
# 1       52431    Mexico
# 2       44781        UK
# 3     1512234       USA
# 4    21234567   Morocco
# 5         N/A      <NA>
```

You could run into problems if a country calling code plus the first digit or so of a phone number matches another country calling code, but as far as I understand, country calling codes and area codes are usually designed to avoid that.

I would advise to look for a robust way of separating the country calling codes from your phone numbers first and then do exact matching on the levels of your country calling codes vector to make it drastically more efficient.

Comment: much appreciated.
I needed something to get started before I can work on improving the performance of the algo. 
Once again, thanks of the answer and also a nudge in the right direction.